# Can't figure out apache2 web server conf issues

Tags: apache2

http://chefceric.com/

Comes up as default apache2 page. These are my current configurations.

`sites-available` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName chefceric.com
    ServerAlias www.chefceric.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ceric/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/ceric/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-chefceric.com.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-chefceric.com.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

And:

```
a2ensite chefceric.com
```

the site comes up using the direct link with the path. but for some reason it's not working when using the DNS, and yes the ip address is correct on the DNS, still apache default.

**I used the `a2dissite 000-default`**

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It looks the problem is wrong name of your configuration file. It must be `chefceric.com.conf`, because these configuration files are involved into the Apache's configuration by the next directive in `apache2.conf`:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

So, if this is the case, the steps should be:

```
a2dissite chefceric.com
mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/chefceric.com /etc/apache2/sites-available/chefceric.com.conf
a2ensite chefceric.com.conf
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: lightpd was my problem. someone on the www-data group add xampp and didn't bother telling the rest. 

Thanks for the help. (deleting the file made it function.)